# Outside VPN traffic not able to ping site-to-site VPN remote site

Tags: vpn, cisco-asa, site-to-site-vpn, anyconnect

we have two ASA 5510s one in 8.4(4) and one in 8.2(5) in a site-to-site VPN setup. All internal traffic is working smoothly.

Site/Subnet A: 192.100.0.0 - local (8.4(4))
Site/Subnet B: 192.200.0.0 - remote (8.2(5))
VPN Users: 192.100.40.0 - assigned by ASA

When you VPN into the network, all traffic hits Site A, and everything on subnet A is accessible.

Site B however, is completely inaccessible for VPN users. All machines on subnet B, the firewall itself, etc... is not reachable by ping or otherwise.

I downgraded to 8.2 and then went back up to 8.4 on the Site A ASA. Site B is now running 8.2(5).

Thank you much in advance and I hope I have been thorough enough.

Comment: Sounds to me like you're maybe missing a route between your VPN network of 192.100.40.0/24 and your Site B 192.200.0.0 network. Does that route exist?

Comment: He must have a route to 192.200.0.0, as he's able to pass traffic over the vpn tunnel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was a combination of the NAT rule and the Site-to-Site ACL. For some reason, the ACL settings were not sticking because of a conflict in the configuration due to the 8.2 - 8.4 upgrade. It is complicated for me to explain, but after an 1.5 hours on the phone with Cisco, they rebuilt the site-to-site tunnel in 8.4(4) and it set the ACL correctly. If you ever run into this again and you just updated from 8.2 - 8.4, the solution seems to be to rebuild the site-to-site from scratch. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible you're missing a NAT, but first make sure you've got this line added to your config, **same-security-traffic permit intra-interface**.

Cisco's command reference for it is here [ver8.4 Command Ref](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa84/command/reference/s1.html#wp1444448).  It will allow "hairpinning", which is disabled by default.  In ASDM, it is located under Configuration -> Device Setup -> Interfaces.  At the bottom of the page.

Before you create NATs, you should create objects to reference in the NATs:

object network obj-192.100.0.0
subnet 192.100.0.0 255.255.255.0
description Subnet A

object network obj-192.200.0.0
subnet 192.200.0.0 255.255.255.0
description Subnet B

object network obj-192.100.40.0
subnet 192.100.40.0 255.255.255.0
description Remote Access VPN Users

The NATs from your remote access subnet to your subnet B would be:

nat (outside,outside) source static obj-192.100.40.0 obj-192.100.40.0 destination static 192.200.0.0 192.200.0.0

Comment: Thanks, I checked that and it is there (and the checkbox is checked). I am stumped.

Comment: I tried this, and it still does not seem to allow traffic. What outputs do you need?

Comment: Any ideas? I have tries all variations on this I could think of. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Anyone? Sort of bumping this. I am really stuck here still. Cisco is taking forever to get back to me on their support.